# CTE variables, Exec procedure and order by EmployeeLevel

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_ReturnEmployeeOrg]
( @BusinessEntityID int = 21 ) **-- NOT WORKING**
AS
SELECT * FROM HumanResources.Employee
;WITH cte_Emp (EmployeeID,ManagerID,Title,EmployeeName,ManagerName,EmployeeLevel)
AS
-- Anchor member definition
(SELECT e.BusinessEntityID,e.MaritalStatus,e.JobTitle,
        CAST(c.LastName + ',' + c.FirstName AS VARCHAR(200)),
        CAST ('N/A' AS VARCHAR(200)),
        CAST (0 AS INT)
    FROM HumanResources.Employee e 
    INNER JOIN Person.Person c
        ON e.BusinessEntityID = c.BusinessEntityID
        WHERE e.BusinessEntityID = @BusinessEntityID

 UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition 
SELECT  e.BusinessEntityID,e.MaritalStatus,e.JobTitle, 
                CAST(c.LastName + ',' + c.FirstName AS VARCHAR(200)),
                CAST ('N/A' AS VARCHAR(200)),
                CAST (0 AS INT)
        FROM HumanResources.Employee e
        INNER JOIN Person.Person c
        ON e.BusinessEntityID = c.BusinessEntityID)
        ORDER BY EmployeeLevel - **NOT WORKING**

       EXEC p_ReturnEmployeeOrg 21)
```

-- exec is **NOT WORKING, the results are raw data instead of BusinessEntityID = 21**

Comment: What do you mean by raw data? Please show your expected output and actual output.

Comment: I just need to filter BusinessEntityID = 21 (as declared above) but the I am getting ALL (raw) data.  Thank you.

Comment: Um.. you defined the cte but where is it actually used in the stored procedure? The SP is simply gonna return all the records from the humanresources.employee table from the first select statement (SELECT * FROM HumanResources.Employee) regardless of what you pass in as the businessentityid!!

Comment: The query is wrong at so many levels. You've not provided DDL, you've mangled `MaritalStatus` into "ManagerID", `BusinessEntityID` into "EmployeeID"... not closed off the CTE. Assigned an extraneous default to a SP input param. As a self-proclaimed `newbie` I would suggest learning at least one of those things first rather than trying the whole thing. Pick up a book on TSQL programming or take an online course. StackOverflow is not a tutorial site, it's for answers to specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to place the first select statement at the end of the stored procedure? There are three pertinent issues to your stored procedure. Firstly, the CTE's defined but not used in the stored procedure (this is the reason why your sp is returning everything from the employee table). Secondly your exec statement actually cuts through the middle of the CTE definition (I think this might have been formatting error during your posting). The order by statement in the CTE is probably going to cause an error. It's best to move it out of the CTE.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_ReturnEmployeeOrg]
( @BusinessEntityID int = 21 ) 
AS

;WITH cte_Emp (EmployeeID,ManagerID,Title,EmployeeName,ManagerName,EmployeeLevel)
AS
-- Anchor member definition
(SELECT e.BusinessEntityID,e.MaritalStatus,e.JobTitle,
        CAST(c.LastName + ',' + c.FirstName AS VARCHAR(200)),
        CAST ('N/A' AS VARCHAR(200)),
        CAST (0 AS INT)
    FROM HumanResources.Employee e 
    INNER JOIN Person.Person c
        ON e.BusinessEntityID = c.BusinessEntityID
        WHERE e.BusinessEntityID = @BusinessEntityID

 UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition 
SELECT  e.BusinessEntityID,e.MaritalStatus,e.JobTitle, 
                CAST(c.LastName + ',' + c.FirstName AS VARCHAR(200)),
                CAST ('N/A' AS VARCHAR(200)),
                CAST (0 AS INT)
        FROM HumanResources.Employee e
        INNER JOIN Person.Person c
        ON e.BusinessEntityID = c.BusinessEntityID)
) 
SELECT * FROM cte_emp ORDER BY EmployeeLevel 
--....................  

EXEC p_ReturnEmployeeOrg 21
```

I moved the select statement down just after the end of the CTE definition and changed the table name from employee to cte_emp. I alos moved your exec statement out of the CTE defintion.

However there are other non-pertinent issues with this. As mentioned by RichardTheKiwi, why is it that you have e.maritalstatus in the CTE definition, but ManagerID in the CTE header? Is businessentityid in the CTE definition meant to be the employeeid in the CTE header?

Comment: @James Jiao  your corrections made a difference.  Thank you for your corrections and I will start from here.  Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge (:

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi You are welcome to edit my answer.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi  Also, it says it's recursive, but it's not really recursive. It's just not going to give him the expected results.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi Hmm. I don't think this is recursive: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c3e3/2   This is very similar to what OP is doing.

Comment: You're right James. Apologies.